# Meaning of end='' in the statement print("\t",end='')?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

This is the function for printing all values in a nested list (taken from Head first with Python).

```
def printall(the_list, level):
    for x in the_list:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            printall(x, level=level + 1)
        else:
            for tab_stop in range(level):
                print("\t", end='')
        print(x)
```

The function is working properly.

The function basically prints the values in a list and if there is a nested list then it print it by a tab space.

Just for a better understanding, what does `end=' '` do?

I am using Python 3.3.5

For 2.7

```
f =  fi.input( files = 'test2.py', inplace = True, backup = '.bak')
for line in f:
    if fi.lineno() == 4:
        print line + '\n'
        print 'extra line'
    else:
        print line + '\n'
```

as of 2.6 fileinput does not support with. 
This code appends 3 more lines and prints the appended text on the 3rd new line. and then appends a further 16 empty lines.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The default value of `end` is `\n` meaning that after the `print` statement it will print a new line. So simply stated `end` is what you want to be printed after the `print` statement has been executed

Eg: - `print ("hello",end=" +")` will print `hello +`

Comment: My aspergers requires me to correct the output to `hello + `.

Comment: @smassey Yeah, but the problem is even though I have given a space, it is not shown :(

Comment: You can't really just end and end doesn't really equate to a newline

`end=' '` actually means that you want a space after the end of the statement instead of a new line character. So you can continue on the same line with "Whatever"

Example
`print ("Hello World")
x = '20'
print (x, x, x, x)
print ("HI HI")`
Would print out 1st line = "Hello World" 2nd line = 20 20 20 20 3rd line = "HI HI"
However Example
`print ("Hello World")
x = '20'
print (x, x, x, x, end=' ')
print ("HI HI")`
Would print out 1st line = Hello World 2nd line = 20 20 20 20 HI HI

Comment: end will work on python 3 not 2.7

Comment: @ShyamGupta yes

Answer (score 4):

See the documentation for the print function: [print()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print)

The content of `end` is printed after the thing you want to print. By default it contains a newline (`"\n"`) but it can be changed to something else, like an empty string.