# Reset the cursor to newline AFTER setting it to the beginning using `end="\r"`

Tags: python

The `print()` function has a really useful argument called [`end`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312273/meaning-of-end-in-the-statement-print-t-end), which allows you to customize the text at the end of print and the placement of the cursor after print. For example, you can use `end='\r'` to [print the text on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7715690/6908282) multiple times, which is really useful to create progress bar's and % complete statements.

But how do I reset the cursor back to a new-line after setting it to the beginning? For example, the following code:

```py
import datetime

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
sampleRange = range(10)
for i in range(10):
    i=i+1
    percentComplete = str(i/len(sampleRange)*100)
    print(percentComplete + "% done", end="\r")
    if i==5:
        timeTaken = str(datetime.datetime.now() - start_time)
        print(str(i) + "loops done in " + timeTaken)
```

results in an output:

```sh
5loops done in 0:00:00.001001
100.0% done
```

But the expected output is:

```sh
50% done
5loops done in 0:00:00.001001
100.0% done
```

This helps in adding milestones to a progress bar when necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to simply add a `print()` statement in the if condition before the second `print(...)` statement, without any arguments to reset the cursor back to its default behavior

```py
#...
    if i==5:
        print() # this sends the cursor to the next line without changing anything in the current line
        print(str(i) + "loops done in " + timeTaken)
```

---

### TIP

For curious folks, below are the resources on how to print progress-bar in terminal using python:

- [Text Progress Bar in the Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console) is the simplest solution to get started
- [Python Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160699/python-progress-bar) has some advanced use cases and variation of customized progress-bars